# How can I edit a custom dialog background?

Tags: android, layout, dialog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryvcL.png)

I am new to Android programming, I am still learning
I want to remove this deformed part, but I tried in every way and it did not work out. Can you help me?

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/click"
        android:text="تم"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.27999997" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words, to get rid of empty area from dialog you have to make the dialog background transparent so that it can just display the used area. 
Try

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

or

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```